# How to structure a react project correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is the sample use case diagram, which may occur in my project.

[image]

Parent - root component

It will have many dependent components and those child components will have N of grandchild components. It also has independent components/ unlinked components, these components will get props from parent/child 1/ child 2 or 3.

Here, I doubt that which one of these suitable for this kind of stuff. **Redux or react context**.

If I'm go with, React context:

Parent -> contains main state -> provider

Child 1, 2, 3 -> consumers

grandchild -> consumers

Here Child 1,2,3 may have its own state functionalities, so I have to make it as a provider.
So already parent component is a provider, so how do I make all the child 1,2,3 as both consumers and providers, or I have to make as nested providers.

If I go with this approach, how do I share state/props with independent components?

I would like to know whether the **independent component which is not part of parent/child hierarchy**, how does this component will gets those parent/child components state/props?

Consider this situation you're about to start a new react project, between you're confused about choosing redux or context. The business model / requirement contains drag and drop, lots of dynamic and async ops involved so it may leads to N of child components. So here Redux is the solution to go with?

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you mean by independent component. As far as I know, there's no such thing in React. The component must be rendered by a parent of some sort. Is the parent to the independent component the child 1/2/3? Or is it rendered by some completely different parent/root context? It would be easier if you also provided some code examples of what you have tried so far, so we can see your exact problem.

Comment: If by independent component you mean a component that is not part of parent-child component hierarchy view - I think the least you need to do for such component is to connect it to the context provided by the Parent - (as Child 1, 2, 3). When you work with some global state like Redux, which is not related to any particular component but rather a stateful Store, then, by linking independent comp. to such state you don't need to put it in Parent context. It's important to understand difference between component view hierarchy (jsx) and structure of state in the app and components' access to it.

Comment: independent component is like it's not part of parent/child hierarchy, but it will use those components state/props and i'm about to start new project, that project scenario is like it expand to multiple components so i'm struck at which way is optimal  @Phoenix1355

Comment: @Learntocode do you mean it's reusable then? So it doesn't belong directly to that child or parent, but can be reused in any context? Either way, you'd still have to give it some parent of a sort so that it can be rendered. And whichever parent it has, should pass the state/props to it.

Comment: Okay... I'm still confused about what you're trying to achieve. I don't think what you want to do is possible in React. No matter what, a rendered component must be a part of a parent/child hierarchy that leads back to the root application component somehow. If you want to make it reusable so that it will retrieve whichever Context is provided to it, regardless of which project it is used in, you'd still have to render the component as a child somewhere. But if that's what you want, then going with the Context API probably is the best idea.

Comment: idea is simple you have 10 components and in that 8 are interlinked(parent-child), between you have 2 other components which are not linked with those 8. How do we pass those 8 components state to this not linked component.

Answer (score 0):

Where you decide to store state is entirely up to what makes sense in the application.
If you find that you are passing down data deep into your hierarchy then it may make sense to store it some form of global state (redux) etc.

If the data is needed by just say the parent component then this can be passed up through an event handler function.

There is no definitive answer you need to do what makes sense for your application.

There are of course tools that will allow you to connect to your data store at various points in your hierarchy, (react-redux) etc, but my advice would be to think carefully if the data you need is needed by the rest of the application before you consider using such devices.

And it's not clear what is meant by an indepedent component. It must exist somewher in your component hierarchy with data passed down in a top down fashion.

Comment: can you check my question again please, edited for better understanding !

Comment: hi your diagram still doesn't make sense. your 'independent' component would need to be a child of 'child 3', in which case you would select data from your provider (store) or pass data to your 'parent' component's local state, which would in turn update its children. a code example would really help  us

Answer (score 0):

These questions gets asked quite a lot, and there's no clear cut way to do things. Lately I've been drawn more and more towards [Apollo for react](https://www.apollographql.com/). It is amazing because it rethinks how to work with data in general in your application. It has obvious benefits when you use it with a graph server of sorts, is a little worth but still powerful with REST API's (still interfaces with them as GraphQL), but in general it's just a strong cache/state management system.

If you use their [local state management](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state/) (formerly known as `apollo-link-state`) you get the same interface to work with remote data and local data.

In terms of the structure I have all components as individual as I can - obviously sometimes there's a parent that passes some props, but often times if it's a sibling relation ship or if the components live in different places they can subscribe to the same data. The benefit of this is that if that particular set of data updates, the component that subscribes to it will get notified, receive the appropriate props and act accordingly. You can think of the cache/apollo as an event bus that will notify all particular listeners. On top of that there is very, very little boiler.

Cases I use it is local-state user management. Is the user logged in? Is there an auth token? If I have multiple components that subscribe to the same list of data that comes remotely, then they will all get updated. If I add a new item to the data off-line, (e.g. if the connection is gone) it will get reflected across components.

Using this system you can also leverage the fact that you can persist data in your localstorage as triggers - so a button click in one component can trigger changes to multiple other components, without those two components ever being in contact with each other - they only subscribe to the same data. This obviously gets a little more spicy, as you shouldn't use a data-store for events, but sometimes I prefer it over an odd hook that travels through your component tree.

There's also a ton of benefits with predicting UI changes and updating before you get responses and what not, but that's another topic.

My project structure currently is:

```
- Components
  - component
     - component.tsx
     - component.test.jsx
     - component.modules.scss
```

That way each component is as self contained as I can possibly make it.